# I'm getting an error alert even if I enter a proper email like ab@gmail.com

Tags: javascript, html

When I enter the correct email format like `"abcd@gmail.com"`, I'm getting an invalid email address alert. What's the mistake which I have done in my code?

```
var pattern = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

if (element.value == '') {
    alert('Please enter valid email address');
    element.focus();
    element.value = '';                                      
    return false;
} else {
    if (!pattern.test(element)) {                          
        alert('Invalid Email Address');
        element.focus();
        element.value = '';
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("Email is valid");
        return true;
    }
}

}

Email:<input type="text" id="email" onblur="return validateEmail(this)" /> 

Contact:<input type="text" id="contact"/>
```

Comment: Which `alert()` is being triggered? `var pattern` is probably incorrect

Comment: invalid email address alert is getting trigered

Answer (score 3):

Because an object is not a string

Look at what you are comparing, it is no value

```
if (element.value == '') {   <-- you reference the value here
if (!pattern.test(element))  <-- you reference the element here, not the value
```

so yoour reg expression is checking

```
!pattern.test("[object Object]")
```

add the missing `.value` and it should work

```
if (!pattern.test(element.value))
```

Comment: im just passing element as a argument from onblur

Comment: yea i got it..tq..lt me hav a try

Comment: @epascarelo i have doubt in jquery file retrieving from DB..can u resolve